# Remove first part of a string that haven't fixed length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I ran into some problems with my code and I don't know how to fix it. So my problem:

On a View of my application, there is a filepath displayed like this:

```
/resume/attachment/12/yaml_error_complete.yml
```

But I only want the filename as Output, means:

```
yaml_error_complete.yml
```

How can i achieve this? I tried with several options like `string.slice!` etc, but it doesn't work, since the number after "attachment" is increased by 1 for every single upload. At beginning I thought about to simply remove 2 chars, don't matter what they are. But then i ran into another problem that happens when the 100 file is uploaded. In this case i would have to remove 3 chars instead of 2, and i'm again at the beginning of my problem.

May someone of you can help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try "/resume/attachment/12/yaml_error_complete.yml".split('/').last

Comment: @BalaKarthik Thank you very much, worked perfect!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you need to retrieve the file of a path.

for ex if your file name is `"/resume/attachment/12/yaml_error_complete.yml"`

Then try this one

```
"/resume/attachment/12/yaml_error_complete.yml".split('/').last
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question right, then, maybe it should help you:

```
a = "/resume/attachment/12/yaml_error_complete.yml"
a.split('/').last
#=> "yaml_error_complete.yml"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for! Ruby is so nice... but its so difficult for a newbie to find all those options!

Comment: @Twinfriends Your welcome! Next time you can search options on the
 [ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.com) :)

Comment: Thanks. I know ruby-doc and I often try to find what I need. Often it works great, but sometimes, like this time, i'm just stuck because i don't know what to search. But exactly for those problems there is SO! :D

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the sulution with `split('/')` you could do the following

```
File.basename("/resume/attachment/12/yaml_error_complete.yml")
```